# How to model user/group membership with constraint of user and group must be same organization?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a few tables that define organizations, users, and groups:
- Organization(id, name)
- User(id, name, Organization)
- Group(id, name, Organization)

I am stumped when trying to add a GroupMembership table with a constraint between User and Group:
- GroupMembership(id, User, Group)

I would like the database to enforce that all records in the GroupMembership table have User.Organization == Group.Organziation. Conceptually, Users can be members of any/all Groups defined by their associated Organization.

Is there a design pattern for this?

Comment: See this question: [Many to Many and Weak Entities](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities/34050#34050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to enforce this rule with procedural logic, then you can add `organization` to the primary key of `Group` and `User`.  This would propagate `Organization` down to your membership intersection table.  This allows you to use declarative referential integrity to impose this restriction.

Personally, I would think twice about using DRI for this particular rule.  It can be done, but the side-effects of the solution might be worse than the original problem.